# Neo4J User-Defined Function - unable to set property

Tags: neo4j

I have a User-defined function that receives a List of Nodes.

I am trying to set a property on these nodes, but I get the following error "Token create operations are not allowed for user 'neo4j' with FULL restricted to READ'

```
@UserFunction
public String doStuff(@Name("nodeList") List<Node> nodeList) {
  String resultStr="";
  nodeList.foreach(node -> {
    //The next line errors out
    node.setProperty("Status","updated");
    //...
   }
   return resultStr;
 }
```

Comment: from the docs... *"User-defined functions are a simpler form of procedures that are **read-only** and always return a single value. Although they are not as powerful in capability, they are often easier to use and more efficient than procedures for many common tasks."*

Comment: So for your next step, if this performs write operations it needs to be a procedure, not a function.